# Coding a runge kutta 4 numeric method in scilab to solve a system of equations in the cressman model describing neuronal membrane activity

Tags: scilab, runge-kutta

I have twenty equations that I worked from the Hodgkin Huxley model to the cressman model and I'd like to analyse the model that I obtained through numeric methods.

Can someone help me code these equations with scilab using a runge kutta IV method?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the built-in ODE solver `ode` of scilab? Fixed-step RK4 while not bad is almost always sub-optimal compared with adaptive step-size solvers.

Comment: However, my english is not good and I have a hard time undersanding what you meant by "Fixed-step RK4 while not bad" .

Comment: When you learn numerical methods, you start with Euler and second order methods with fixed step size. They are easy to analyze but bad in their numerical results. With fixed step size in most cases the best, in terms of effort to precision, is RK4. However, embedded methods with adaptive step size take less, sometimes much less, effort for the same precision.

Comment: Would you recommend i try another numerical method for the cressman model i'm working on ? Is this method easy to implement in a scilab code, for example?

Comment: Anyhow, let me thank you for responding me. I do appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use without programming anything but the user ODE function, directly out-of-the-box,

```
y = ode(y0, t0, times, rtol, atol, odefunc)
```

where `(t0,y0)` is the initial points, `times` the list of times that samples of the solution are reported for in `y`, and `function dydt = odefunc(t, y)` is the function implementing the derivatives.

As there is a proven and robust algorithm behind it, you can assume that the actual numerical errors are related in meaningful ways to the tolerances `rtol, atol`.

For examples see the built-in documentation and online examples such as [Solving ODE in Scilab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455667/solving-ode-in-scilab), [Using scilab to solve and plot differential equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477235/using-scilab-to-solve-and-plot-differential-equations)

Comment: Tank you for your help. I did not check the links you provided(soooo much work) but, as it is, i thank you for your support. It is very helpful.